# Handling encoding when creating a slug using JQuery AJAX and PHP 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encode, slug

I want to generate a slug on blur of a specific field.

When the user loses focus on a text field, I want to send the text in the text field to the controller which should return the slug.

Right now when I send "Hello World", I get "Hello-20World" as the slugified string. JQuery encodes "Hello World" as "Hello%20World" before making the GET request, the controller receives "Hello World" as "Hello%20World" and the slug method parses the "%20" character as "-20".

I have added the JQuery code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });

        $('#PagesTitle').blur(function(){
            var slugUrl = "slugify/" + $('#PagesTitle').val();
            $.get(
                slugUrl,
                function(responseText) {
                    $('#PagesSlug').html(responseText);
                },
                "text"
            );
        })
   });
```

Am I sending the text data incorrectly to the server or should the server respond in a certain way to the JQuery call?